# Scala ZIO.bracket: handling errors of releasing resource

Tags: scala, zio

I want to create a directory, then do something with the directory and finally delete it. I'm using a bracket idiom for that.

```
val fs: FileSystem = ???
val path = ???
ZIO.bracket[Any, Throwable, Path, Unit](
    acquire = ZIO{fs.mkdirs(path); path},
    release = p => ZIO.succeed(fs.delete(p, true)),
    use = p => ZIO{()})
```

Deleting a directory is apparently an error-prone action. But `release` function has to always succeed. So I have to use `ZIO.succeed` which looks wrong.

How to close the resource properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion on gitter: https://gitter.im/ZIO/Core?at=5d44552a7a151629e10f68a3

`release` can't return error because otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish between an error from `release` and an error from `use`.

Possible solutions:

1) `release = ZIO.succeed(action)` - turns an error into unrecoverable error. 
When `release` is safe or indeed unrecoverable.

2) `release = Task{action}.ignore` - ignores potential error.

3) make error a value. So `Zio.bracket` will be of type `ZIO[R, E, Either[FinalizerError, Good]]`. When recovery is really important.

1 and 2 are meant to cover vast majority of usecases.